# Upgrade Required websocket

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, сервер, веб-сервер, websocket

Когда я запускаю локальный сервер пишет **Upgrade Required**
как это исправить ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сервер**

```
var WS = new require("ws");

var ws = new WS.Server({
       port: 8080
   });

   ws.on("connection", function(ws) {

   console.log("New player connected.")
});
```

**Клиент**

```
var socket = new WebSocet("ws://localhost:8082");

socket.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log("Connect ");
};

socket.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log(e.data.toString());
};
```

Comment: А клиентский код вы каким способом запускаете?

Answer (score 1):

Вы запускаете WebSocket сервер на 8080 порту и подключаетесь по нему в браузере через адресную строку. Браузер посылает запрос по HTTP протоколу на WebSocket сервер, что и вызывает необходимость провести "Upgrade"

Вот простой пример конфигурации Nginx для поддержки подключения к вебсокетам (взято [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/171757/)):

```
location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}
```

Скорее всего ваш **Клиент** расположен на другом порту. Смените адрес в браузере, либо порт в инициализации сервера с 8080 на 8082, как указано в клиенте.

Comment: Смена порта не помогла

Comment: /home/tonchor/more/project1/server.js:61
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
               ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:576:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:653:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3